# Jupyterhub installation Hub Pod Pending state

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub, amazon-eks

I am trying to install jupyterhub on Kubernetes, hub pod is pending with due to resources. When i did describe pods

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling  2m25s (x6 over 2m25s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)

 Warning  FailedScheduling  55s (x4 over 2m25s)    default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 2 node(s) had no available volume zone.
It also shows that the requests is 
 Requests:
    cpu:      500m
    memory:   512Mi
```

I followed the installation steps as mentioned from the resource https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-jupyterhub.html

My config.yaml configuration looks like below. I am using Kubernetes EKS ( AWS) 
 proxy:
  secretToken: ""

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage    

singleuser:
  cpu:
    limit: 1
    guarantee: 0.02
  memory:
    limit: 2G
    guarantee: 512M
  storage:
    dynamic:
      storageClass: gp2

# culling old users, unit: seconds    
cull:
  enabled: true
  timeout: 1800
  every: 300

auth:
  admin:
    users:
      - admin
    access: false

# allow image to be prepulled
prePuller:
  continuous:
    enabled: true

# pod priority - scale up nodes ahead of real users arrivals
# user scheduler - pack users tight on some nodes
scheduling:
  userScheduler:
    enabled: true
  podPriority:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Please post first page of TOP so we know how much RAM and SWAP space is available.

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue you reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775632)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Jupyterhub hub pod is failing with no available volume zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775632/installing-jupyterhub-hub-pod-is-failing-with-no-available-volume-zone)