# Installing Jupyterhub hub pod is failing with no available volume zone

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub, amazon-eks

When trying to install Jupyterhub on Kubernetes (EKS) I am getting below error in the Hub pod. This is output of describe pod. There was similar issue reported and i tried the solution but it didn't work.

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  52s (x2 over 52s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 2 node(s) had no available volume zone.
```

### This is my pvc.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: standard
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2  
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - us-east-1a
    - us-east-1b
    - us-east-1c
```

---

## Source: jupyterhub/templates/hub/pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hub-db-dir
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS documentation, an EBS volume and the instance to which it attaches must be in the same Availability Zone. ([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html))

In that case, the solution is using only one AZ.

> Kubernetes itself supports many other storage backends that could be
>   used zone independently, but of course with different properties (like
>   performance, pricing, cloud provider support, ...). For example there
>   is [AWS EFS](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs) that can be used in any AZ within an AWS region but with its own tradeoffs (e.g.  [kubernetes-incubator/external-storage#1030](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/1030)).

This is a know issue reported [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/6267).

Comment: If this answer helped you, please don't forget to mark as accepted it and/or upvote it. Thank you.